# Array in Angularjs Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs application view.html, I have following code as shown below:

```
<select ng-model="models.category">
         <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{ [category.id , category.title] }}">
        </select>
```

When i access models.category using expression.
 `{{ models.category}}` 
The output is.
`[1,"sports"]`
But, all i want is to display is `1 and sports` in different part of my application view.

Comment: Its because of `value="{{ [category.id , category.title] }}`

Comment: Plz mark as answer if it is the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by doing the following

```
{{category.id + ' ' + category.title}}
```

I personally think it's even better to use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) if you use a select because the `ng-model` used on the select is always a string if you use ng-repeat

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.title for option in categories track by option.id"
  ng-model="models.category"></select>
```

and on another part of you application you can use the `models.category.title`and `models.category.id`.

Comment: i want to show 1 and sport in different part with in my application view.

Comment: maybe it's better to show what you want then, because u said you want 1 sports in the value. But take a look at my answer above. Use the ng-options instead of a repeat. This way you can have the complete category inside your ng-model which you can use everywhere on your page.